# Unity Camera animation not working?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on some kind of temple run game project just for the educational purpose. And I have created a script which should focus on character from little bit high and then change its position to characters. Like in temple run when the camera slowly lerps toward the player when the game scripts. Here is my script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraMotor : MonoBehaviour {
    private Vector3 ofset;
    private Vector3 characterposition;

    private float transition =0.0f;
    private float animationduration = 2.0f;
    private Vector3 animationoffset = new Vector3(0,2f,2f);
    void Start () {
        ofset = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<CharacterController> ().transform.position - this.transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        characterposition = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<CharacterController> ().transform.position - ofset;
        characterposition.x = 1.3f;
        characterposition.y = Mathf.Clamp (characterposition.y, 3f, 5f);
        if (transition > 1.0f) {
            this.transform.position = characterposition;
        } else {
            this.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (characterposition + animationoffset, characterposition, transition);
            transition =  Time.deltaTime* 1 / animationduration;
            this.transform.LookAt (characterposition, Vector3.up);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close but your transition value needs to continually increase for your Lerp to work properly. Try changing this line:

```
transition =  Time.deltaTime* 1 / animationduration;
```

to

```
transition +=  Time.deltaTime* 1 / animationduration;
```

Answer (score 1):

Following line is wrong

```
this.transform.LookAt (characterposition, Vector3.up);
```

LookAt() method requires Transform type parameter, not Vector3. Try use these

```
private Vector3 ofset;
private Vector3 characterposition;
private CharacterController characterCon;

private float transition =0.0f;
private float animationduration = 2.0f;
private Vector3 animationoffset = new Vector3(0,2f,2f);

void Start () {
    ofset = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<CharacterController> ().transform.position - this.transform.position;
    characterCon = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<CharacterController> ().GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}

void Update () {

    characterposition = characterCon.transform.position - ofset;
    characterposition.x = 1.3f;
    characterposition.y = Mathf.Clamp (characterposition.y, 3f, 5f);
    if (transition > 1.0f) {
        this.transform.position = characterposition;
    } else {
        this.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (characterposition + animationoffset, characterposition, transition);
        transition =  Time.deltaTime * 1 / animationduration;
    }

    this.transform.LookAt (characterCon.transform, Vector3.up);
}
```

Also you calling FindObjectOfType method at every frame causes poor performances.
Take a look at following link [LookAt](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html)